# Which notation for confusion matrix is more accurate?

Tags: classification, confusion-matrix

I found this:
[image]
http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/confusion_matrix/confusion_matrix.html

defining TP,FP,TN, FN as:
[image]

while on the other hand I often find it in such form:

[image]
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs578/2003fa/performance_measures.pdf

Which notation for confusion matrix is more accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unfortunately no consensus on the correct notation. You can also find, like on the Wikipedia page about [type I and type II errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_I_and_type_II_errors), a third notation:

[image]

My preference goes to the first notation you mention (http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/confusion_matrix/confusion_matrix.html), as it extends to any number of classes unlike the other notations (since label 0 is usually assigned to the negative class, and label 1 is assigned to the positive class).